# asynchronous WatchEffect function generate infinite loop

Tags: vuejs3

I'm making a composable following [the documentation example](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#async-state-example) but the `watchEffect` triggers itself and generates infinite call to the API. [Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dkuwcw?file=src/useAxiosAPICall.ts)

```
import { useAxios } from '@vueuse/integrations/useAxios';
import { ComputedRef, isRef, ref, Ref, unref, watchEffect } from 'vue';

export function useGetRequest(id: string | Ref<string> | ComputedRef<string>) {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  const data: Ref<any | undefined> = ref(undefined);

  async function doGetRequest() {
    useAxios<any>('https://dummyjson.com/products/' + unref(id), {
      method: 'GET',
      headers,
    }).then((res) => (data.value = res.data.value));
  }

  if (isRef(id)) {
    watchEffect(doGetRequest);
  } else {
    doGetRequest();
  }

  return { data };
}
```

The documentation state that

> watchEffect only tracks dependencies during its synchronous execution.

Can you explain why the watchEffect is triggered in this example and how to use it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from `useAxios()`, which internally sets some refs that are changed when the request finishes, and when used in `watchEffect()`, those refs are added to the tracked dependencies, so they trigger the effect.

To resolve it, replace `watchEffect()` with a regular watcher, where you can set the watched refs manually:

```
 watch(id, doGetRequest, {immediate: true});
```

---

About the line in the documentation

> watchEffect only tracks dependencies during its synchronous execution.

It means that in your method, refs used in the `.then()` are not triggering the effect (unless they are also used before). So in your case, a change to `data.value` would not trigger the effect.